# Android java pinned Shortcuts generated material letter icon

Tags: java, android, shortcut, android-8.0-oreo, android-shortcut

As seen in the image below, the second shortcuts the one with the letter T red.

How can I generate such an icon to be able to put it in the shortcuts in the icon attribute?

By setting up:

- the color of the text
- the background color
- the number of letters

[image]

Answer (score 0):

create a xml file in drawable folder, example this file name : "oval_text" and paste this code to xml file:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">
<gradient
    android:angle="270"
   android:startColor="#8ac53e"
   android:endColor="#8ac53e"
    android:type="linear" />
<size
    android:width="90dp"
    android:height="90dp"/>
```

And, create a xml file in folder layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ImageView
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:src="@drawable/oval_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="T"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

View this image: [image]

Comment: App shortcuts are not built with layout XML, so this does not answer the question.